# Adding only new list items to list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so looking for the simplest solution possible (also, not looking for a jQuery solution).

I'm trying to add clicked list items to a new list, only if the clicked list item isn't already in the new list. I have managed to add the clicked list item to the new list, but I fail to create a functioning `if` statement that checks the new list for the current item.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var ul = document.getElementById('bulk');

    ul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var target = e.target;
        while (target && target.parentNode !== ul) {
            target = target.parentNode; 
            if(!target) { return; } 
        }
        if (target.tagName === 'LI'){
            var node = document.createElement("LI");
            var textnode = document.createTextNode(target.id);
            var textarea = document.getElementById("test1");
            if (!textarea.querySelector(target.id)) {
                node.appendChild(textnode);
                document.getElementById("test1").appendChild(node);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="bulk">
            <li id="banana"><a href="#"><b>banana</b></a></li>
            <li id="apple"><a href="#"><b>apple</b></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="test1"></ul><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One problem is you are creating elements with duplicate IDs.  That usually causes problems.  The second (and probably actual issue) is that you're using querySelector to search for an id but you forgot the "#" (so, `if (!textarea.querySelector("#" + target.id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not supposed to have multiple elements with the same ID in a single document, I changed things so the unique ID of each element is in a dataset attribute `data-id`.

Beyond that, it's just a question of using `querySelector()` to figure out whether such a node already is in the destination list.

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('bulk');
var destination = document.getElementById("test1");

ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  while (target && target.parentNode !== ul) {
    target = target.parentNode;
    if (!target) {
      return;
    }
  }
  if (target.tagName === 'LI') {
    var id = target.dataset.id;
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    node.dataset.id = id;
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("element with id " + id);
    if (destination.querySelector("[data-id=" + id + "]")) {
      return;
    }
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    destination.appendChild(node);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="bulk">
  <li data-id="banana"><a href="#"><b>banana</b></a></li>
  <li data-id="apple"><a href="#"><b>apple</b></a></li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul id="test1">
</ul>
```